# why is ASCII.GetBytes returning wrong bytes

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, ascii

Im creating a class and converting it into xml.

The problem is that when i convert the class xml string into bytes
the `ASCII.GetBytes` return a byte array with
an extra character in the beginning of the `ascArray`

It's always a ? character so the xml starts like this

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Why is this happening?

This is the code:

```
  WorkItem p = new WorkItem();

  // Fill the class with whatever need to be sent to client
  OneItem posts1 = new OneItem();
  posts1.id = "id 1";
  posts1.username = "hasse";
  posts1.message = "hej again";
  posts1.time = "time1";
  p.setPost(posts1);

  OneItem posts2 = new OneItem();
  posts2.id = "id 2";
  posts2.username = "bella";
  posts2.message = "hej again again";
  posts2.time = "time2";
  p.setPost(posts2);

  // convert the class WorkItem to xml
  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WorkItem));
  XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
  xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, p);

  // send the xml version of WorkItem to client
  byte[] data = memoryStream.ToArray();
  clientStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  Console.WriteLine(" send.." + data);
  clientStream.Close();
```

Comment: How does the input `XmlizedString` look like if you breakpoint at `Byte[] ascArray= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XmlizedString);`

Comment: That's strange, It has the leading ? also but it's only visible if i copy/paste to content of the XmlizedString

Comment: So why is UTF8ByteArrayToString adding an extra byte

Comment: @Erik: It's not. You should look at the byte array that is passed to `UTF8ByteArray`. I'm pretty sure you'll find it starts with 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF, which is the UTF-8 representation of the byte order mark. That's being decoded by `UTF8ByteArrayToString` into a single *character* (not byte) - but that character can't be represented in ASCII. Fundamentally, you're applying a lossy transformation here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the data starts with a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which can't be represented in ASCII.

It's not clear why you're doing what you're doing in the first place, particularly around the `MemoryStream`. Why are you creating a UTF-8 encoded byte array, then decoding that to a string (and we don't know what `UTF8ByteArrayToString` does), then converting it *back* to a byte array? Why not just write the byte array straight to the client to start with? If you need the data as a string, I'd use a subclass of `StringWriter` which advertises that it uses UTF-8 as the encoding. If you *don't* need it as a string, just stick to the byte array.

Note that even aside from this first character, the fact that you've got an XML document encoded in UTF-8 means there may well be other non-ASCII characters in the string. Why are you using ASCII at all here?

EDIT: Just to be clear, you're fundamentally applying a lossy transformation, *and* doing it needlessly. Even if you want a local copy of the data, you should have something like this:

```
// Removed bad try/catch block - don't just catch Exception, and don't
// just swallow exceptions
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WorkItem));
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, p);

// Removed pointless conversion to/from string
// Removed pointless BinaryWriter (just use the stream)

// An alternative would be memoryStream.WriteTo(clientStream);
byte[] data = memoryStream.ToArray();
clientStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
Console.WriteLine(" send.." + data);

// Removed Close calls - you should use "using" statements to dispose of
// streams automatically.
```

Comment: I want to send the class to a java client. Thats why i first convert the class to XML and then to bytes.

Comment: @Erik: But you're converting it *directly* to bytes, in a `MemoryStream`. Why are you then converting it to a string and then *back* to bytes, using the wrong encoding? Why are you even using a `MemoryStream` instead of creating the `XmlTextWriter` straight from `clientStream`?

Comment: @Erik: I've edited my answer with better code, including a bunch of comments explaining what I've done.

Comment: Now i get even more bad character at the beginning, ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Work... Updating the question with the new code. Maybe the reason is that I in the java client do like this String XMlString = dataInputStream.readLine();

Comment: Those three "characters" are definitely the UTF-8 byte order mark